# Why flexbox is not aligning items as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am creating the top section of a webpage, which has a full page image with an overlay.  On top of the overlay, I am placing a logo on the top left and I want to place the nav menu below it towards the bottom of the page vertically.

I have a section called  which is set as display: flex.  This has 2 child elements: logo and navbar.  Based on my finding if header is defined as flex then the immediate children can override the 'align-items' property, but in my case it is not working.

If you look at my html/css you will see i have a logo section highlighted in yellow, I want to move that logo (which will be an image) to the bottom, so I should be able to set inside the logo div --> align-self: felx-end since its a immediate child of a parent container which is defined as flex.  However, its not working.

Last there is a vertical menu-bar and for visibility purposes,  I have given it a pink background for now.  I want to move this 'navbar' section of mine to roughly the bottom of the page.  I don't want it right under the logo on the next line.  This section is also a child element of a parent that is defined as flex.

On some sites, I have seen that the child elements are being defined as display: flex, but doesn't that defeat the purpose since children element can override the parent element by calling align-self?   I appreciate all your help.

Any other advice for this beginner then please don't hesitate to tell me if I'm doing something else wrong in my code below.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  background-image: url("/assets/images/3017085.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.main-container::after {
  content: "";
  display:  block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  background: #cd5b1d; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #cd5b1d 0%, #051928 0%, #091c2b 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #cd5b1d 0%,#051928 0%,#091c2b 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #cd5b1d 0%,#051928 0%,#091c2b 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cd5b1d', endColorstr='#091c2b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index:  0;
}

.main-container > * {
  z-index:  10;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}


.header{
  display: flex;
  flex:  1 auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
}

.logo {  /*  FIRST IMMEDIATE CHILD ELEMENT OF HEADER (FLEX) */
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  align-content: flex-end;
}

.logo img {
  width: 250px; 
}

.navbar {  /*  SECOND IMMEDIATE CHILD ELEMENT OF HEADER (FLEX) */
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 9em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">  <!-- main-container --> 
  <header class="header">  <!-- header -->
    <div class="logo">  <!-- logo -->
      <a href="index.html">
        <p>LOGO HERE</p>
      </a>
    </div>  <!-- /logo -->

    <div class = "navbar">  <!-- navbar --> 
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 1</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 2</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 3</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 4</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>  <!-- /navbar --> 

  </header>  <!-- /header -->

</div>  <!-- /main-container -->
```

Comment: You can find all the information about flexbox you need, here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

For your logo I fixed your problem but I did not understand what you want exactly for menu items, could you explain better? (I did new edits for your pink part but I do not know if that's what you wanted)

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
  background-image: url("/assets/images/3017085.jpg");
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.main-container::after {
  content: "";
  display:  block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  background: #cd5b1d; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #cd5b1d 0%, #051928 0%, #091c2b 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #cd5b1d 0%,#051928 0%,#091c2b 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #cd5b1d 0%,#051928 0%,#091c2b 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cd5b1d', endColorstr='#091c2b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index:  0;
}

.main-container > * {
  z-index:  10;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
}


.header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo {  /*  FIRST IMMEDIATE CHILD ELEMENT OF HEADER (FLEX) */
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  height: 3em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.logo img {
  width: 250px; 
}

.navbar {  /*  SECOND IMMEDIATE CHILD ELEMENT OF HEADER (FLEX) */
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  z-index: 5;
position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
}

.nav-links li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 9em;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">  <!-- main-container --> 
  <header class="header">  <!-- header -->
    <div class="logo">  <!-- logo -->
      <a href="index.html">
        <p>LOGO HERE</p>
      </a>
    </div>  <!-- /logo -->

    <div class = "navbar">  <!-- navbar --> 
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 1</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 2</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 3</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 4</li>
        <li class="nav-item">Menu Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>  <!-- /navbar --> 

  </header>  <!-- /header -->

</div>  <!-- /main-container -->
```